# Deductions and Salary... Asking the boss for an adjustment

Tags: salaried-pay, taxes, china

Recently because of some conditions of the country (China) and taxes etc. my FINAL salary now is less than the previous year (around 20% less). I talked with the HR department and after some explanations, they said that I should talk to the boss in order to fix this problem.

I would like to talk to the boss and ask for an adjustment.

I can't find the words to use and how to talk with the boss. 
I'm looking for some suggestions, and the way to ask for it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Comment: @aaaaasaysreinstateMonica I think he's in China, as mentioned in the post

Comment: @gnat It's not quite the same. Boss and employee had agreed on a salary that was not too high (pre tax) for the boss and not too low (after tax) for the employee. Now the taxes have massively changed, so the boss will understand that the employee is not happy with the situation, and wouldn't have accepted the job under these terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a simple matter to talk to your boss, there is no need to overthink it. Schedule a discussion with your boss (face to face). During the discussion explain your boss what you already told us here, in simple words - like you did here.

Example:

> Hello boss, the HR department told me to talk you about this. My problem is that this year my income is 20% less compared to last year, because ... (reasons). This makes me unhappy, and I wonder if the company can do anything to compensate for the money loss.

Two things can happen:

1. The boss actually does something to help you.
2. The boss discards your request.

In the second case, there is probably not much you can do to get more money, except:

1. Negotiate with the boss for a different position in the company (if available), for a better pay.
2. Find a new job.

Comment: I just wanted to find the "right words" like "unhappy"  and  "wonder".. actually it is solved. finally, I finished with a negotiation. He will increase the payment by 15% I think that's fair. thanks a lot for your time

Comment: You are welcome.